CustomPaint widget's dynamic size
I'm trying to make a message bubble for my chat. The problem is that even if the message is short, the widget takes all the width. If you remove the Column and display only the message, it works. You can try to use this widget inside a Scaffold :
class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? sender;
  final String hour;
  final String message;
  final bool isOwn;

  const MessageBubble(
      {super.key,
      required this.sender,
      required this.hour,
      required this.message,
      required this.isOwn});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
        painter: CustomChatBubble(
            color: isOwn ? blue : const Color(0xFFEAE9E9), isOwn: isOwn),
        child: Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 9, bottom: 7, left: 15, right: 15),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                if (sender != null)
                  Text(sender!,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      style: TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)),
                Text(message),
                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Text(hour))
              ]),
        ));
  }
}

class CustomChatBubble extends CustomPainter {
  CustomChatBubble({required this.color, required this.isOwn});

  final Color color;
  final bool isOwn;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = color;

    Path paintBubbleTail() {
      Path path;
      if (!isOwn) {
        path = Path()
          ..moveTo(5, size.height - 5)
          ..quadraticBezierTo(-5, size.height, -16, size.height - 4)
          ..quadraticBezierTo(-5, size.height - 5, 0, size.height - 17);
      } else {
        path = Path()
          ..moveTo(size.width - 6, size.height - 4)
          ..quadraticBezierTo(
              size.width + 5, size.height, size.width + 16, size.height - 4)
          ..quadraticBezierTo(
              size.width + 5, size.height - 5, size.width, size.height - 17);
      }
      return path;
    }

    final RRect bubbleBody = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
        const Radius.circular(16));
    final Path bubbleTail = paintBubbleTail();

    canvas.drawRRect(bubbleBody, paint);
    canvas.drawPath(bubbleTail, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }
}

Edit: Removing Align() solves the problem
